# why doesn't ng-pattern work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

In the following form, the `ng-pattern` validation does not work.
The regex works as i expect in `https://regex101.com`.
It should show `.custom-error` div if the user enters some special character.

Where am I doing it wrong?

```
<form novalidate name="myForm">
    <label for="subnet">only alphanumeric</label>
    <input type="text" name="subnet" ng-model="subnet" class="form-control"
           id="subnet" required ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]\s*/">
    <div class="custom-error" ng-show="myForm.subnet.$error.pattern">
        not in one of predefined characters
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the div with custom-error should become visible if the user entered a special character like @.
but it does not happen. in you plunk too

Comment: I have just updated the plunker. Once see it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ng-show="myForm.subnet.$error.pattern" is wrong. I read the official angular doc and i think you should try ng-show="!myForm.subnet.$valid" instead :

```
<input type="text" name="subnet" ng-model="subnet" class="form-control" id="subnet" required ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]\s*/">
<div class="custom-error" ng-show="!myForm.subnet.$valid">
   not in one of predefined characters
</div>
```

It hope it will help you

Comment: doesn't OP want to show that message when things go wrong and not when they are valid?

Comment: You're right, just use ng-show="!myForm.subnet.$valid" instead =)

Answer (score -1):

Change the ng-pattern code to `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff\s]*$/"`. It will work now.

Working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XKwo8V0tlwdD2teMRYAd?p=preview)

All the best.

Comment: plunker doesn't work.. it says not valid character for all inputs

Comment: I just updated the plunker. Once see it. I just corrected the code for his error. He should write the correct regex for that to happen. Anyways, I updated that.

Comment: this do work, but not in my case, as the form also accepts some international characters like äöü

Comment: @Fawad, I updated the plunker. Now it is working fine for all your requirements. Once check it.